# Several problems with Popup (does not hide)

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a small test-application to illustrate the behavior I do not understand: 2 buttons, if the mouse enters the left button a popup is shown (works), if the mouse enters the right button the popup should dissapear instantly (does not work). In my real application I have no buttons, only in this example for simple test, so the mouse movement is important and button-clicks cannot be used.

What I see is the following behavior:

- If the popup is shown, the right button mouse-enter (hide) does not react at all, it seems that the popup has gotten focus, I have to click in the main window before the right mouse-enter becomes enabled. Setting Popup.Focusable=false (XAML) or trying to give focus to the grid (C# code) just after setting Popup.Isopen=true does not help.
- Once I try to hide the popup by setting Popup.IsOpen=false, the popup stays visible and does not disappear. Only when I click the main window topbar, or when I hover the minimize button for example which shows a tooltip, the popup suddenly disappears. Calling UpdateLayout() on several UI elements does not help.

I'd like the following:

1. Once the popup is shown, the hide button should still react on mouse-enter.
2. Setting Popup.IsOpen=false should directly let the popup disappear.

See code below, XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="MyWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Margin="100" Background="Green">

        <TextBox x:Name="MyText" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="0,50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>

        <Button Width="75" Height="50" Margin="20,100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Content="Show" MouseEnter="MouseEnterShow"></Button>
        <Button Width="75" Height="50" Margin="20,100" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Content="Hide" MouseEnter="MouseEnterHide"></Button>

        <Popup x:Name="MyPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid}" Placement="RelativePoint"
               AllowsTransparency="false" IsOpen="False" StaysOpen="False"
               Focusable="False"
               Width="200" Height="200"                   
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               HorizontalOffset="-50" VerticalOffset="-50">
            <Grid>
                <Canvas Background="BlanchedAlmond" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MouseEnterShow(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
        MyGrid.Focus();// Does not help

        MyText.Text    = "Show";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Show");
    }

    private void MouseEnterHide(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
        MyGrid.UpdateLayout();// Does not help

        MyText.Text    = "Hide";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hide");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some brute forcing, I've managed to make it work:

1.Set the Popup property StaysOpen to **true**, instead of false

2.Code behind

```
private void MouseEnterShow(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void MouseEnterHide(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: It's a step forward, thanks. The mouse-enter on the hide button indeed responds now when the popup is shown, but for some reason after "Popup.IsOpen=false" the popup still stays visible until I click the mainwindow topbar or hover the minimize button. Strange...

Comment: Seems to work now, once I set "AllowsTransparency="true"". But I do not understand the rationale behind this...